# Get stuck in The MainPage When i try to navigate to the AccountPage afater navigating from MainPage to Account and back in MAUI

Tags: asp.net, mvvm, navigation, maui

I am working on a MAUI project, i have a navigation problem. When i navigate from the MainPage to the AccountPage and back everithing goes as aspected but when i try to navigate to the AccountPage again i get the MainPage. When i try to another tab from the menu works fine but again when i try Navigate to the Account page i get again only the MainPage.

Tried to change the way i navigate as follows:

```cs
using ReFeelApp.MAUI.ViewModels;

namespace ReFeelApp.MAUI.Pages;

public partial class AccountPage : ContentPage
{
    private AccountViewModel _viewModel;

    public AccountPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new AccountViewModel();
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }

  
    private  void OnArrowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the Home page (Main page)
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        
    }


    private void OnAccountImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented)
         {
             Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
         }
         else
         {
             Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true;
         }
```

Comment: if you want to navigate **back** from the `AccountPage` to the `MainPage`, why are you navigating to a **new instance** of `MainPage`?  Normally "back" navigation is handled automatically and you do not need to do anything special

Comment: You don’t show the xaml that defines Shell, tabs, ShellContent. If MainPage is part of that xaml, DO NOT do `PushAsync(new MainPage())`. See maui shell navigation doc; use a shell method that takes a route. Or see the doc for how to pop.